# How can I print the square root latex function in python?

Tags: python

I'm creating a graph using the matplotlib library and I want to set the title to be y=sqrt(x), except the sqrt is replaced by the square root symbol.

An example of what I want to do can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMzii.png) in the title - note that the title has the square root symbol.

I'm writing this code in Google Colab by the way.

Comment: matplotlib supports latex symbols, see documentation here: https://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html

Comment: If you have an import such as `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, you can try `plt.title(r'$y = \sqrt{x}$')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subset TeX markup in any matplotlib text string by placing it inside a pair of dollar signs ($).

Here is a simple example:

```
# plain text
plt.title('alpha > beta')
produces “alpha > beta”.
```

Whereas this:

```
# math text
plt.title(r'$\alpha > \beta$')
```

In your case it would be like:

```
r'$\sqrt{2}$'
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, exe. That work. This one works:

```
func=r"$\sqrt{x}$"
plt.plot(x,f(x),label=f"Graph of y = {func}")
# And to show the lengend in the diagram:
plt.legend()
```

You can also use superscript, such as x^2, x^3 and so on:

```
func=r"$\sqrt{x^2 + 3x}$"
```